# loop appends last row n times to dict, instead of each row 1 time python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

So I get this information from a home page that i put in dictinary in the method "getPersInfo(ID)".

When i want to make a list of dictionaries with the following code:

```
person_dict = {"PERS_ID": 'ini', "PERS_FIRSTNAME": 'ini',"PERS_NAME": 'ini',"PERS_TITLE": 'ini' ,"SITE_ID": 'ini',"PERS_COUNTRY": 'ini'}
listOfPersons = []
for a in range(5,8):
    listOfPersons.append(getPersInfo(a))
    print getPersInfo(a)
print listOfPersons
```

I get this ouput:
(5,8 is just random)

```
{'PERS_COUNTRY': 'EE', 'SITE_ID': 'null', 'PERS_ID': '5', 'PERS_FIRSTNAME': 'null', 'PERS_TITLE': 'null', 'PERS_NAME': 'null'}
{'PERS_COUNTRY': 'EE', 'SITE_ID': 'null', 'PERS_ID': '6', 'PERS_FIRSTNAME': 'null', 'PERS_TITLE': 'null', 'PERS_NAME': 'null'}
{'PERS_COUNTRY': 'EE', 'SITE_ID': '1101', 'PERS_ID': '7', 'PERS_FIRSTNAME': 'null', 'PERS_TITLE': 'null', 'PERS_NAME': 'null'}

[{'PERS_COUNTRY': 'EE', 'SITE_ID': '1101', 'PERS_ID': '7', 'PERS_FIRSTNAME': 'null', 'PERS_TITLE': 'null', 'PERS_NAME': 'null'}, 
{'PERS_COUNTRY': 'EE', 'SITE_ID': '1101', 'PERS_ID': '7', 'PERS_FIRSTNAME': 'null', 'PERS_TITLE': 'null', 'PERS_NAME': 'null'}, 
{'PERS_COUNTRY': 'EE', 'SITE_ID': '1101', 'PERS_ID': '7', 'PERS_FIRSTNAME': 'null', 'PERS_TITLE': 'null', 'PERS_NAME': 'null'}]
```

So... I basically just get the last row the amount if time i iterate. (this has been tested for other cases)

What could explain this, when the output is correct when printing?

Is it something with the appending to my list?

Comment: `getPersInfo` is probably re-using a dictionary. If you want to store it you need to make a copy somewhere, either before returning it from `getPersInfo` or before putting it in `listOfPersons`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mostly a shot in the dark, since your information is quite sparse, but it looks like you updated just one `dict` object, returned it with `getPersInfo` and then appended it to the list. So you have a list with three identical objects. You can test this with `listOfPersons[0] is listOfPersons[1]`.

Anyway, if you append a copy of the returned `dict`, this won't happen:

```
listOfPersons = []
for a in range(5,8):
    listOfPersons.append(dict(getPersInfo(a)))
    print getPersInfo(a)
print listOfPersons
```